# How to get all <a> tag under the <div> in testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

In selenium query for selector, if my selector value was (#div-id a). It return all a tags.
Does in testcafe  is it posible this to selector function? i just want to avoid looping  to get all a tags.

**Code Sample**

```
const element = selector('#div-id').find()
var get = await brandUrls.hasAttribute();
console.log(get);
```

**Actual element attached**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is also possible to achieve the desired behavior with TestCafè in a similar way:

```js
import { Selector } from "testcafe";

// one option
const firstLinkSelector = Selector("#directoryLink-1 a");

// another option
const secondLinkSelector = Selector("#directoryLink-1").find("a");
```

Read more about the find()-method [here](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402750/reference/test-api/selector/find).